# Renaming the files and move to other path

Tags: shell, scripting, rename

I need to rename the files given below and move to some other path

```
1234551abcde20140718023216001.txt.809047512.2014_07_07_13:47:44
000001abcde20140718023216001.txt.34568.001.2014_07_07_13:50:44
44444abcded20140718023216001.txt.1111111.2014_07_07_13:47:44
```

expected Result

```
1234551abcde20140718023216001.txt.809047512
000001abcde20140718023216001.txt.34568.001
44444abcded20140718023216001.txt.1111111
```

only I need to remove the timestamp attached every time with the filenames,and move it to other directory in AIX

For your reference I had tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
file1=`echo 1234551abcde20140718023216001.txt.809047512.2014_07_07_13:47:44 | awk -F "." '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i!= 1) f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}'`
echo $file1
```

Comment: do you have `rename` by larry wall

Comment: I didnt use "rename" option Not sure if it will work for multiple files,and then move to other path

Comment: The `rename` command I am writing about can do both at same time. (all rename/mv tools I have used on Unix can rename and move at same time). Beware the `rename` you have may not be the same rename, this one is written in purl written by Robin Barker and Larry Wall.

Answer (score 0):

Awk isn't going to make your life easier. You can use the suffix removal syntax: `${x%.*}` is the value of the variable `x` with the shortest suffix of the form `.*` removed.

```
for x in *.txt.*.*; do
  mv "$x" "/other/directory/${x%.*}"
done
```